# How to tell Javascript script to only run in the Header of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a website owner who uses X Theme on Wordpress for website development. The theme has an option where you can easily add custom JS, but it is global by default. This owner wants the JS script to only run in the header of the site.

What is the easiest way to go about achieving this?

Thanks,
Mr. Robot

Comment: Add it to the header of the site.

Comment: Huh? Only run in the header? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: "only run in the header of the site" makes no sense. Scripts run on entire pages not just certain parts of a page.

Comment: I interpret the question to mean the site owner doesn't want the script to work properly if it isn't added to the header.  Which doesn't make any more sense.  Just add it to the header if that's what the client wants.  Or maybe "header" refers not to the document head, but instead to the UI elements comprising the top of the page.  Which also doesn't make much sense.  Why have a script that can only do its thing in one location?  Is this question asking how to cripple a script so it can only be used in one place?

Comment: haha. I knew I'd get this kind of response. Their request is odd. They have a js script that they do not want to manually add to the header, they want to add it to the whole of the site, but have it point to and thus run only in the header. I know this is stupid and I'll likely have to tell them they will have to add it ,manually to the header, not through their theme's global JS editor. lol. Thanks

Comment: I'm interpreting this question to mean that you just want JavaScript to access and manipulate a certain element of the DOM. Unfortunately you can't do that. JavaScript has access to the entire DOM. The only way this would be possible is if the header was another document (loaded in an iframe)

Comment: I'm interpreting this question to mean that neither the OP or whoever "they" are have any idea whatsoever how javascript works or, for that matter, what it actually does.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what type of Javascript code is, most tracking scripts like Google requires it to be in the head tag. I don't see why any other code needs to be in head. There are a few ways to include it in a Wordpress head.

1. Simplest would be to download a plugin: [Plugin Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/)
2. Make a child theme and Enqueue the script. I dont know too much on this one but you can [View it here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Hoping I gave you some ideas on how to continue.